# Compressing JS and CSS

Tags: optimization

I'm using W3TC to caching and minifying my Wordpress. Unfortunately it is not possible to minify and compress all of the files since minifying some of them is crashing the site. My question is, how can I manually compress selected JS and CSS to gzip?

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to minify using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) packages. [Gulp Uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) for JS, [Gulp CSS Min](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssmin) for CSS.

As for `GZip`, you'll need to enable that on your server config - Apache using `mod_deflate` in `.htaccess` and In `IIS`, you can set it up in "website properties" (Tab Services), and then allow "compress application files". Finally check and see if you have it enabled using a service like [Check GZip Compression](http://checkgzipcompression.com/).

The article [My Advanced Gulp Workflow for WordPress Themes](https://ahmadawais.com/my-advanced-gulp-workflow-for-wordpress-themes/) will probably help you get a better understanding of the process but keep in mind there are several ways to approach this based on your needs.

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) are also alternative task runners. Go the app route with something like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/), [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) or [Crunch](https://getcrunch.co/). Or minify JS online with something like [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Comment: `GZip` compression is already enabled for my site, as W3TC is already compressing many files that could be automatically minified. Unfortunately there are some `JS` and `CSS` that I couldn't minify automatically with the plugin. So I have now approximately 30 different scripts and styles, already minified manually, and would love to deliver them compressed, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You start by creating a gulp task to merge and minify those into a single file, then enqueue that file (js/blah.min.js) in WordPress. GZip handles compression from source to client from your server so you only need to minify/uglify/concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

There is an nice openopen-source PHP minifier called [PHPWee](https://github.com/searchturbine/phpwee-php-minifier) avalable for do this task. This support for HTML, XHTML, HTML5, CSS 1-3 and Javascript. You have to download PHPWee and install it in your theme directory or create a plugin using it.

Comment: +1 for exposing a new tool that do not require additional software, but it will not help much with JS and CSS files of themes and plugins without some extra not very trivial coding

Comment: Sorry @MarkKaplun, it's not a good way to scale. Once you build your files locally they become minified and require very little to no processing power. Unless your creating new style dynamically it makes no sense to offload this process to the server. Case in point, jQuery gives you an uncompressed and compressed link - not an algorithm to transfer on the fly. Besides, who codes in CCS anymore over SCSS or LESS? In which case you'll need a compiler.

Comment: @jgraup, totally agree with you, but most people lack the knowledge of how to run grunt, and it is not a replacement for any plugin because it requires node.js IIRC which means it can not be deployed on shared hosts. Now with 4.7 you also have the css customization which can not be minified by grunt.

Comment: Agreed. When I first started out I was looking for ways to minify on the server myself. If the emphasis here is always with enqueue rather than inline, I opt to push the responsible route.